# Combine multiple rows as JSON object in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am very new to pyspark and want to perform following operation on the Data Frame. For rows having similar id I need to combine the associated columns in a JSON block. As shown in example below the output should be 1 JSON block with columns secId, names and path.

| id | secId | names | path | bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | [{“area” : “en”, “value” : “name1” }, {“area” : “sp”, “value” : “name2”}] | [abc, xyz] | bin1 |
| 1 | 13 | [{“area” : “en”, “value” : “name3” }, {“area” : “sp”, “value” : “name4”}] | [klm, nop] | bin1 |

Need output as

| id | bin | json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bin1 | [{“secId” : 12,“names” : [{“area” : “en”, “value” : “name1” }, {“area” : “sp”, “value” : “name2”}],“path” : [abc, xyz]},{“secId” : 13,“names” : [{“area” : “en”, “value” : “name3” }, {“area” : “sp”, “value” : “name4”}],“path” : [klm, mno]}] |

[image]

It would be helpful if anyone can provide some guidelines on doing this.

Thank you

Comment: please post sample data as text, not as images.

Comment: sure, updated the question with text as well

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620268/convert-pyspark-dataframe-into-nested-json-structure) for an example

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was trying to do something similar but I when I do df.show() I am getting : 

An error occurred while calling o3426.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 143.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 143.0 (TID 647, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed

Do you know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Spark 'struct' function to creates Scala map structure (key -> value).
2. Spark 'to_json' function to create a json structure.
3. Do a groupby on id and bin columns and use collect_list function to create result you want.

   ```
   import pyspark.sql.functions as F
   df.withColumn('json', F.to_json(F.struct("secId", "names", "path"))).groupby('id', 'bin').agg(F.collect_list('json')).show(5, False)
   ```